# Magnitude of F about line CD (Mechanics, 3D vector system)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, statics

I am having trouble with this question:

[image]

I will write out the question below to make it easier for other people googling the question to find it:

2/139 If the magnitude of the moment of F about line CD is 50 Nm, determine the magnitude of F.

**I know that** $\vec M=\vec r \times \vec F$

**What I have tried:**

Calculating $\vec M$ as following:

$\vec {CD} = (0.4, 0, -0.2)$ please note how I set up coordinate system (x and y is in bottom and z upward according to right-hand rule)

$|\vec{CD}|$=$\frac{1}{\sqrt{0.4^2+0.2^2}}=2.2$

$\vec M = 50 \times 2.2 (0.4, 0, -0.2)$=$(44, 0, -22)Nm$

I now set $\vec F=(f_1, f_2, f_3)$

then try to find some vector $\vec r$. I have tried $\vec CA$ and $\vec DA$ but no matter what vector I choose I end up with something like $0.2f_1=44$ $0.4f_1=0$ after cross product, which is an impossible system of equation to solve. What am I doing wrong? If $\vec r$ is wrong, please explain why. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how $\vec F$ can even make a rotation around $\vec CD$ in the first place but I guess this is more of a theoretical question...

Comment: Remember also that $|\vec{M}|=|\vec{r}\times\vec{F}|= |\vec{r}||\vec{F}|\sin{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the vectors. This will make life much easier

Comment: @Triatticus why do I need that for this problem? Or do you mean more general?

Comment: Then $\frac{|M|}{|r|\sin{\theta}}=|F|$

Comment: Try this $\begin{aligned}M=\left| \overrightarrow {r}\times \overrightarrow {F}\right| =\left| r\right| \cdot \left| F\right| \cdot \sin \left( \varphi \right) \\
\overrightarrow {r}\cdot \overrightarrow {F}=\left| r\right| \cdot \left| F\right| \cdot \cos \left( \varphi \right) \end{aligned}$

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you know the direction of the vector $\boldsymbol{F}$ and therefore $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ *are not independent*. Use just one unknown $F$ along the correct direction and the problem becomes solvable.

Consider the line about which the moment is measured with the direction

$$ \boldsymbol{e} = \frac{ \boldsymbol{r}_D - \boldsymbol{r}_C }{ \| \boldsymbol{r}_D - \boldsymbol{r}_C \| } = \frac{ \pmatrix{0.4 \\ -0.2 \\ 0}}{ \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}} = \pmatrix{2/\sqrt{5} \\ -1/\sqrt{5} \\ 0} $$

and the force vector

$$ \boldsymbol{F} =  \frac{ \boldsymbol{r}_B - \boldsymbol{r}_A }{ \| \boldsymbol{r}_B - \boldsymbol{r}_A \| }\,F = \pmatrix{2/\sqrt{6}\\ 1/\sqrt{6} \\ 
 -1/\sqrt{6}} F $$

The moment vector about point *C* is

$$ \boldsymbol{M} = (\boldsymbol{r}_A - \boldsymbol{r}_C) \times \boldsymbol{F} = \pmatrix{0 \\ -1/5 \\ -1/5} \times \pmatrix{2/\sqrt{6}\\ 1/\sqrt{6} \\ 
 -1/\sqrt{6}} F = \pmatrix{\sqrt{6}/15 \\ -\sqrt{6}/15 \\ \sqrt{6}/15 } F$$

The projection of the moment along the line is supposed to be 50

$$ 50 = \boldsymbol{e} \cdot \boldsymbol{M} =\pmatrix{2/\sqrt{5} \\ -1/\sqrt{5} \\ 0}  \cdot \pmatrix{\sqrt{6}/15 \\ -\sqrt{6}/15 \\ \sqrt{6}/15 }  F = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{25} F $$

$$\Rightarrow\; F = \frac{125 \sqrt{30}}{3} = 228.22 $$

I used the following coordinate system.

[image: CSYS]

A quick shortcut to this calculation is the vector triple product

$$ M = \boldsymbol{e} \cdot ( \boldsymbol{r}_A-\boldsymbol{r}_C) \times \boldsymbol{F} $$

$$ 50 = \pmatrix{2/\sqrt{5} \\ -1/\sqrt{5} \\ 0} \cdot \left[ \pmatrix{0 \\ -1/5 \\ -1/5} \times \pmatrix{2/\sqrt{6}\\ 1/\sqrt{6} \\ 
 -1/\sqrt{6}} \right] F $$ $$ \boxed{ 50 = \frac{\sqrt{30}}{25} F }$$

Comment: I am not sure how you got your value of $\mathbf M$?

Comment: I used $$ \begin{aligned} \boldsymbol{r}_A & = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0 \\ 0.2} & \boldsymbol{r}_B & = \pmatrix{0.4 \\ 0.2 \\ 0} \\ \boldsymbol{r}_C & = \pmatrix{0 \\ 0.2 \\ 0.4} & \boldsymbol{r}_D & = \pmatrix{0.4 \\ 0 \\ 0.4} \end{aligned} $$ and the formulas above. I might have made a typo somewhere, so I am checking now.

Comment: @Farcher - I edited the answer such that the numbers reflect the equations. I had switched points _C_ and _D_ by mistake.

Comment: @Farcher - Now the expression $$ \boldsymbol{M} = (\boldsymbol{r}_A - \boldsymbol{r}_C) \times \boldsymbol{F} $$ returns the value shown in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for going to all that trouble. I made the comment because I thought that I was doing something wrong!

Comment: @Farcher - no trouble at all. I hope this answer has been helpful to you.